# How to send several strings separated by comma to be used in the WHERE IN clause through 1 SqlParameter?

Tags: c#, t-sql, ado.net

I've a query that looks like:

```
string sqlText = @"SELECT col1, col3, col3              
                   FROM table
                   WHERE col1 IN (@listOFValues)";

string listOfValues = GetListOfValues(userName);
paramList.Add(new SqlParameter("@listOFValues", listOFValues));
//..

private string GetListOfValues(string userName)
{
   var dt = ExecuteSqlQueryReturnsDataTable(userName); //this returns a datatable.

   string listOfValues = new StringBuilder();

   if(dt.Rows.Count == 1)
        {
            listOfValues.Append("'" + dt.Rows[0]["myColumnName"] + "'");
        }
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 1)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                listOfValues.Append("'" + dt.Rows[i]["myColumnName"] + "', ");
            }

            listOfValues.Append("'" + dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1]["myColumnName"] + "'");
        }
        return listOfValues.ToString();
}
```

Bottom line, all I want is to be able to generate something like `'val1', 'val2', 'val3'` to be plugged in the **WHERE** clause like this  `WHERE col1 IN ('val1', 'val2', 'val3')`

Thanks for helping

Comment: As of now what you are getting in `listOFValues` whats went wrong when executing the command

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, it's a little dangerous to rely on just commas, since your data may contain one, causing the only thing to break.

With that note, you could do the following:

```
string sqlText = @"
    SELECT col1, col3, col3              
    FROM table
    WHERE col1 IN ({0})";

string[] arrOfValues = GetListOfValues(userName).Split(',');
string[] paramArray = arrOfValues.Select((x, i) => "@value" + i).ToArray();
cmd.CommandText = string.Format(sqlText, string.Join(",", paramArray));

for (int i = 0; i < arrOfValues.Length; ++i)
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@value" + i, arrOfValues[i]));
}
```

Comment: So what you mean is that the query will look something like `WHERE col1 IN (@value1, @value2, @value3)"` then send the same number of paramaters. Ok, I'll try it.

Comment: Thank you so much. That's a time saver technique.